# How can I use jquery/javascript to search for a string and replace on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very annoying validation bug from a plugin that is embedding a video.  I can't change the plugin and need to use it to show the video.  Is there a way that I could use js to search for the & and replace it with &amp?

This is the string that it needs to be replaced in:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/72874423?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0;api=1
```

I tried this, but unfortunately it isn't working:

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function(){

var str = $( "iframe" ).attr( "src" );
str = str.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
$( "iframe" ).attr( "src",str );

    });

})(jQuery, document);
```

That is the only iframe on the page.

Comment: Yes there is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: If you want to use the HTML entity, then you have to write `&amp;`, not `&amp`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it but still no difference. Here is the page: http://www.bbmthemes.com/themes/modular/  I added the jquery in settings.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/72874423?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0;api=1";
str = str.replace(/&/g,"&amp");
alert(str);
```

Comment: How would I then put str into the website in place of the original code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Anton. Explanation of the code will be helpful.

Comment: @fender967: Depends on where the URL is. You can change an elements attribute with `.attr`, its property with `.prop` and its content with `.text`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

Comment: Lets say I wanted to replace the src attribute in a "<iframe src=.."

Comment: Actually, most ideal would be if it could search for ANY <iframe src="..."> and replace any & with &amp.  That way it would be a dynamic fix instead of only working for this specific video, but either one would be greatly appreciated as I am not very familiar with js.